# Why is HTML::TokeParser's get_trimmed_text changing the format of the date?

Tags: html, perl

I'm using HTML::TokeParser to parse a website for a particular field. The field looks as follows

> 09/23/10 - 12:14 PM EDT

However, when I print whatever is received, It displays,

> 2010-09-23 12:14:32.0

Why the inconsistency? Is it recognizing it as a time parameter and converting it to some internal format? If so how can I read it as a string?

Comment: You have to show some code so that people can reproduce the problem on their own.

Comment: Its happening with just one website to which I have to login and I cant reveal that :( .Isn't there a general approach to this issue?

Comment: Print the whole content before you feed it into the TokeParser. If it is already wrong at that time, you have eliminated the parser as source of the problem and this Stack Overflow question would be wrong/invalidated.

Comment: You should find the place in the HTML where the date appears and either just look at it or post it.

Comment: Remember to always post a short example script with sample input that dempnstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it be possible that the value HTML::TokeParser gives you is actually the date that's in the website's HTML, but the website also has some javascript to convert the date into your local timezone?